# For what do we need object storage spaces for django application in production?

Tags: python, django, server, storage

This is first time that I am hosting some of application on server. Its a Django application that is being served on Digital Ocean. I am seeing couple of toturials that are suggesting me to use S3 storage spaces for serving static and media files.

I am not getting why do I need a separate storage space? Can't django own static and media folder serve the purpose? Can anyone clearify?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The point of that separation is low latency.

When you store your data on one server, users from all over the world access this server. For some (which are geographically close) this may be a normal solution, but for those far away there will be big latency.

Under the hood S3 lies CDN. CDN checks the user's geolocation and gives him static/media from the closest storage node.

Have a look [how CDN works](https://www.cloudflare.com/learning/cdn/what-is-a-cdn/).

Comment: My app is target to only one country, means it is not for whole world now. Still then, should I need s3 sorage spaces?

Comment: It depends on your needs. The thing is that giants like Amazon usually have peering with most of internet providers. CDN will deliver your files faster then your server will. For somebody delivering static is ok at 100-150ms. Some use CDN to decrease it to 20-30ms.